# DataFrame to JSON - Then Flatten in Snowflake

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Having trouble effectively transforming a DF object to a JSON Object & then flattening into tabular format in Snowflake.

df:

```
Date           User Interaction
2021-03-28     0
2021-03-28     0
2021-03-28     0
2021-03-28     0
....
```

so I run `df = df.to_json(orient ='columns')` & get the output below:
output:

```
"{\"Day\":{\"0\":\"2021-03-28\",\"1\":\"2021-03-28\",\"2\":\"2021-03-28\",\"3\":\"2021-03-28\",\"4\":\"2021-03-28\",\"5\":\"2021-03-28\",\"6\":\"2021-03-28\",\"7\":\"2021-03-28\",\"8\":\"2021-03-28\",\"9\":\"2021-03-28\",\"10\":\"2021-03-28\",\"11\":\"2021-03-28\",\"12\":\"2021-03-28\",\"13\":\"2021-03-28\",\"14\":\"2021-03-28\",\"15\":\"2021-03-28\",\"16\":\"2021-03-28\",\"17\":\"2021-03-28\",\"18\":\"2021-03-28\",\"19\":\"2021-03-28\",\"20\":\"2021-03-28\",\"21\":\"2021-03-28\",\"22\":\"2021-03-28\",\"23\":\"2021-03-28\",\"24\":\"2021-03-28\",\"25\":\"2021-03-28\",\"26\":\"2021-03-28\",\"27\":\"2021-03-28\",\"28\":\"2021-03-28\",\"29\":\"2021-03-28\",\"30\":\"2021-03-28\",\"31\":\"2021-03-28\",\"32\":\"2021-03-28\",\"33\":\"2021-03-28\",\"34\":\"2021-03-28\",\"35\":\"2021-03-28\",\"36\":\"2021-03-28\",\"37\":\"2021-03-28\",\"38\":\"2021-03-28\",\"39\":\"2021-03-28\",\"40\":\"2021-03-28\",\"41\":\"2021-03-28\",\"42\":\"2021-03-28\",\"43\":\"2021-03-28\",\"44\":\"2021-03-28\",\"45\":\"2021-03-28\",\"46\":\"2021-03-28\",\"47\":\"2021-03-28\",\"48\":\"2021-03-28\",\"49\":\"2021-03-28\",\"50\":\"2021-03-28\",\"51\":\"2021-03-28\",\"52\":\"2021-03-28\",\"53\":\"2021-03-28\",\"54\":\"2021-03-28\",\"55\":\"2021-03-28\",\"56\":\"2021-03-28\",\"57\":\"2021-03-28\",\"58\":\"2021-03-28\",\"59\":\"2021-03-28\",\"60\":\"2021-03-28\",\"61\":\"2021-03-28\",\"62\":\"2021-03-28\",\"63\":\"2021-03-28\",\"64\":\"2021-03-28\",\"65\":\"2021-03-28\",\"66\":\"2021-03-28\",\"67\":\"2021-03-28\",\"68\":\"2021-03-28\",\"69\":\"2021-03-28\",\"70\":\"2021-03-28\",\"71\":\"2021-03-28\",\"72\":\"2021-03-28\",\"73\":\"2021-03-28\",\"74\":\"2021-03-28\",\"75\":\"2021-03-28\",\"76\":\"2021-03-28\",\"77\":\"2021-03-28\",\"78\":\"2021-03-28\",\"79\":\"2021-03-28\",\"80\":\"2021-03-28\",\"81\":\"2021-03-28\",\"82\":\"2021-03-28\",\"83\":\"2021-03-28\",\"84\":\"2021-03-28\",\"85\":\"2021-03-28\",\"86\":\"2021-03-28\",\"87\":\"2021-03-28\",\"88\":\"2021-03-28\",\"89\":\"2021-03-28\",\"90\":\"2021-03-28\",\"91\":\"2021-03-28\",\"92\":\"2021-03-28\",\"93\":\"2021-03-28\",\"94\":\"2021-03-28\",\"95\":\"2021-03-28\",\"96\":\"2021-03-28\",\"97\":\"2021-03-28\",\"98\":\"2021-03-28\",\"99\":\"2021-03-28\",\"100\":\"2021-03-28\",\"101\":\"2021-03-28\",\"102\":\"2021-03-28\",\"103\":\"2021-03-28\",\"104\":\"2021-03-28\",\"105\":\"2021-03-28\",\"106\":\"2021-03-28\",\"107\":\"2021-03-28\",\"108\":\"2021-03-28\",\"109\":\"2021-03-28\",\"110\":\"2021-03-28\",\"111\":\"2021-03-28\",\"112\":\"2021-03-28\",\"113\":\"2021-03-28\",\"114\":\"2021-03-28\",\"115\":\"2021-03-28\",\"116\":\"2021-03-28\",\"117\":\"2021-03-28\",\"118\":\"2021-03-28\",\"119\":\"2021-03-28\",\"120\":\"2021-03-28\",\"121\":\"2021-03-28\",\"122\":\"2021-03-28\",\"123\":\"2021-03-28\",\"124\":\"2021-03-28\",\"125\":\"2021-03-28\",\"126\":\"2021-03-28\",\"127\":\"2021-03-28\",\"128\":\"2021-03-28\",\"129\":\"2021-03-28\",\"130\":\"2021-03-28\",\"131\":\"2021-03-28\",\"132\":\"2021-03-28\",\"133\":\"2021-03-28\",\"134\":\"2021-03-28\",\"135\":\"2021-03-28\",\"136\":\"2021-03-28\",\"137\":\"2021-03-28\",\"138\":\"2021-03-28\",\"139\":\"2021-03-28\",\"140\":\"2021-03-28\",\"141\":\"2021-03-28\",\"142\":\"2021-03-28\",\"143\":\"2021-03-28\",\"144\":\"2021-03-28\",\"145\":\"2021-03-28\",\"146\":\"2021-03-28\",\"147\":\"2021-03-28\",\"148\":\"2021-03-28\",\"149\":\"2021-03-28\",\"150\":\"2021-03-28\",\"151\":\"2021-03-28\",\"152\":\"2021-03-28\",\"153\":\"2021-03-28\",\"154\":\"2021-03-28\",\"155\":\"2021-03-28\",\"156\":\"2021-03-28\",\"157\":\"2021-03-28\",\"158\":\"2021-03-28\",\"159\":\"2021-03-28\",\"160\":\"2021-03-28\",\"161\":\"2021-03-28\",\"162\":\"2021-03-28\",\"163\":\"2021-03-28\",\"164\":\"2021-03-28\",\"165\":\"2021-03-28\",\"166\":\"2021-03-28\",\"167\":\"2021-03-28\",\"168\":\"2021-03-28\",\"169\":\"2021-03-28\",\"170\":\"2021-03-28\",\"171\":\"2021-03-28\",\"172\":\"2021-03-28\",\"173\":\"2021-03-28\",\"174\":\"2021-03-28\",\"175\":\"2021-03-28\",\"176\":\"2021-03-28\",\"177\":\"2021-03-28\",\"178\":\"2021-03-28\",\"179\":\"2021-03-28\",\"180\":\"2021-03-28\",\"181\":\"2021-03-28\",\"182\":\"2021-03-28\",\"183\":\"2021-03-28\",\"184\":\"2021-03-28\",\"185\":\"2021-03-28\",\"186\":\"2021-03-28\",\"187\":\"2021-03-28\",\"188\":\"2021-03-28\",\"189\":\"2021-03-28\",\"190\":\"2021-03-28\",\"191\":\"2021-03-28\",\"192\":\"2021-03-28\",\"193\":\"2021-03-28\",\"194\":\"2021-03-28\",\"195\":\"2021-03-28\",\"196\":\"2021-03-28\",\"197\":\"2021-03-28\",\"198\":\"2021-03-28\",\"199\":\"2021-03-28\",\"200\":\"2021-03-28\",\"201\":\"2021-03-28\",\"202\":\"2021-03-28\",\"203\":\"2021-03-28\",\"204\":\"2021-03-28\",\"205\":\"2021-03-28\",\"206\":\"2021-03-28\",\"207\":\"2021-03-28\",\"208\":\"2021-03-28\",\"209\":\"2021-03-28\",\"210\":\"2021-03-28\",\"211\":\"2021-03-28\",\"212\":\"2021-03-28\",\"213\":\"2021-03-28\",\"214\":\"2021-03-28\",\"215\":\"2021-03-28\",\"216\":\"2021-03-28\",\"217\":\"2021-03-28\",\"218\":\"2021-03-28\",\"219\":\"2021-03-28\",\"220\":\"2021-03-28\",\"221\":\"2021-03-28\",\"222\":\"2021-03-28\",\"223\":\"2021-03-28\",\"224\":\"2021-03-28\",\"225\":\"2021-03-28\",\"226\":\"2021-03-28\"},\"User \\/ Activity\":{\"0\":0,\"1\":0,\"2\":0,\"3\":0,\"4\":0,\"5\":0,\"6\":0,\"7\":0,\"8\":85110000,\"9\":0,\"10\":0,\"11\":0,\"12\":0,\"13\":0,\"14\":0,\"15\":0,\"16\":0,\"17\":0,\"18\":0,\"19\":0,\"20\":0,\"21\":0,\"22\":0,\"23\":27780000,\"24\":0,\"25\":0,\"26\":0,\"27\":0,\"28\":0,\"29\":0,\"30\":0,\"31\":0,\"32\":0,\"33\":0,\"34\":0,\"35\":0,\"36\":0,\"37\":0,\"38\":0,\"39\":0,\"40\":0,\"41\":0,\"42\":0,\"43\":0,\"44\":0,\"45\":0,\"46\":0,\"47\":0,\"48\":0,\"49\":0,\"50\":0,\"51\":0,\"52\":0,\"53\":0,\"54\":0,\"55\":0,\"56\":0,\"57\":0,\"58\":0,\"59\":0,\"60\":0,\"61\":0,\"62\":0,\"63\":0,\"64\":0,\"65\":0,\"66\":0,\"67\":0,\"68\":0,\"69\":0,\"70\":0,\"71\":0,\"72\":0,\"73\":0,\"74\":0,\"75\":0,\"76\":194350000,\"77\":0,\"78\":0,\"79\":0,\"80\":0,\"81\":0,\"82\":0,\"83\":0,\"84\":0,\"85\":0,\"86\":0,\"87\":0,\"88\":0,\"89\":0,\"90\":0,\"91\":0,\"92\":0,\"93\":0,\"94\":0,\"95\":0,\"96\":0,\"97\":0,\"98\":0,\"99\":0,\"100\":0,\"101\":0,\"102\":0,\"103\":0,\"104\":0,\"105\":0,\"106\":51370000,\"107\":0,\"108\":0,\"109\":0,\"110\":0,\"111\":0,\"112\":0,\"113\":0,\"114\":0,\"115\":0,\"116\":0,\"117\":0,\"118\":0,\"119\":0,\"120\":180797500,\"121\":0,\"122\":0,\"123\":0,\"124\":33331250,\"125\":0,\"126\":0,\"127\":0,\"128\":0,\"129\":0,\"130\":0,\"131\":0,\"132\":0,\"133\":0,\"134\":0,\"135\":0,\"136\":0,\"137\":0,\"138\":0,\"139\":0,\"140\":0,\"141\":0,\"142\":0,\"143\":0,\"144\":0,\"145\":0,\"146\":0,\"147\":0,\"148\":0,\"149\":0,\"150\":0,\"151\":0,\"152\":0,\"153\":23210000,\"154\":0,\"155\":0,\"156\":0,\"157\":0,\"158\":0,\"159\":0,\"160\":0,\"161\":0,\"162\":0,\"163\":0,\"164\":0,\"165\":0,\"166\":0,\"167\":0,\"168\":0,\"169\":0,\"170\":0,\"171\":32965000,\"172\":76040000,\"173\":3890000,\"174\":0,\"175\":0,\"176\":0,\"177\":0,\"178\":0,\"179\":0,\"180\":0,\"181\":0,\"182\":0,\"183\":65360000,\"184\":0,\"185\":0,\"186\":0,\"187\":0,\"188\":0,\"189\":0,\"190\":0,\"191\":0,\"192\":0,\"193\":0,\"194\":0,\"195\":0,\"196\":0,\"197\":0,\"198\":0,\"199\":0,\"200\":0,\"201\":0,\"202\":0,\"203\":0,\"204\":0,\"205\":0,\"206\":0,\"207\":0,\"208\":0,\"209\":0,\"210\":0,\"211\":0,\"212\":0,\"213\":0,\"214\":0,\"215\":365435000,\"216\":0,\"217\":0,\"218\":0,\"219\":0,\"220\":0,\"221\":0,\"222\":0,\"223\":0,\"224\":0,\"225\":0,\"226\":0}}"
```

I am trying to select from snowflake to start with

```
Select $1:"Day\"
```

But I am getting all Null

Wondering how I can handle the weird way the columns names were tranformed, how to possibly pass in more arguemnts into the to_json(..) argument to make flattening easier to. Or how to use snowflake sql to flatten the json output above with the strange column names which I guess are now essentially key names.

Comment: Try this maybe?

Select $1:Day

Comment: I get NULL @Anton & when I run just Select $1 - I get what is pasted above

Comment: Then your data might be in a varchar, not variant? Try casting using TO_VARIANT() or PARSE_JSON()

Answer (score 0):

fundamentally this is a rather gross way to process data, as compared to just having it as rows.

Also your column "User \/ Activity" does not match "User Interaction", but if the json is rewritten to to drop the `\\/` this works to access the to object:

```
select 
parse_json('{\"Day\":{\"0\":\"2021-03-28\",\"1\":\"2021-03-28\",\"2\":\"2021-03-28\",\"3\":\"2021-03-28\",\"4\":\"2021-03-28\",\"5\":\"2021-03-28\",\"6\":\"2021-03-28\",\"7\":\"2021-03-28\",\"8\":\"2021-03-28\",\"9\":\"2021-03-28\",\"10\":\"2021-03-28\",\"11\":\"2021-03-28\",\"12\":\"2021-03-28\",\"13\":\"2021-03-28\",\"14\":\"2021-03-28\",\"15\":\"2021-03-28\",\"16\":\"2021-03-28\",\"17\":\"2021-03-28\",\"18\":\"2021-03-28\",\"19\":\"2021-03-28\",\"20\":\"2021-03-28\",\"21\":\"2021-03-28\",\"22\":\"2021-03-28\",\"23\":\"2021-03-28\",\"24\":\"2021-03-28\",\"25\":\"2021-03-28\",\"26\":\"2021-03-28\",\"27\":\"2021-03-28\",\"28\":\"2021-03-28\",\"29\":\"2021-03-28\",\"30\":\"2021-03-28\",\"31\":\"2021-03-28\",\"32\":\"2021-03-28\",\"33\":\"2021-03-28\",\"34\":\"2021-03-28\",\"35\":\"2021-03-28\",\"36\":\"2021-03-28\",\"37\":\"2021-03-28\",\"38\":\"2021-03-28\",\"39\":\"2021-03-28\",\"40\":\"2021-03-28\",\"41\":\"2021-03-28\",\"42\":\"2021-03-28\",\"43\":\"2021-03-28\",\"44\":\"2021-03-28\",\"45\":\"2021-03-28\",\"46\":\"2021-03-28\",\"47\":\"2021-03-28\",\"48\":\"2021-03-28\",\"49\":\"2021-03-28\",\"50\":\"2021-03-28\",\"51\":\"2021-03-28\",\"52\":\"2021-03-28\",\"53\":\"2021-03-28\",\"54\":\"2021-03-28\",\"55\":\"2021-03-28\",\"56\":\"2021-03-28\",\"57\":\"2021-03-28\",\"58\":\"2021-03-28\",\"59\":\"2021-03-28\",\"60\":\"2021-03-28\",\"61\":\"2021-03-28\",\"62\":\"2021-03-28\",\"63\":\"2021-03-28\",\"64\":\"2021-03-28\",\"65\":\"2021-03-28\",\"66\":\"2021-03-28\",\"67\":\"2021-03-28\",\"68\":\"2021-03-28\",\"69\":\"2021-03-28\",\"70\":\"2021-03-28\",\"71\":\"2021-03-28\",\"72\":\"2021-03-28\",\"73\":\"2021-03-28\",\"74\":\"2021-03-28\",\"75\":\"2021-03-28\",\"76\":\"2021-03-28\",\"77\":\"2021-03-28\",\"78\":\"2021-03-28\",\"79\":\"2021-03-28\",\"80\":\"2021-03-28\",\"81\":\"2021-03-28\",\"82\":\"2021-03-28\",\"83\":\"2021-03-28\",\"84\":\"2021-03-28\",\"85\":\"2021-03-28\",\"86\":\"2021-03-28\",\"87\":\"2021-03-28\",\"88\":\"2021-03-28\",\"89\":\"2021-03-28\",\"90\":\"2021-03-28\",\"91\":\"2021-03-28\",\"92\":\"2021-03-28\",\"93\":\"2021-03-28\",\"94\":\"2021-03-28\",\"95\":\"2021-03-28\",\"96\":\"2021-03-28\",\"97\":\"2021-03-28\",\"98\":\"2021-03-28\",\"99\":\"2021-03-28\",\"100\":\"2021-03-28\",\"101\":\"2021-03-28\",\"102\":\"2021-03-28\",\"103\":\"2021-03-28\",\"104\":\"2021-03-28\",\"105\":\"2021-03-28\",\"106\":\"2021-03-28\",\"107\":\"2021-03-28\",\"108\":\"2021-03-28\",\"109\":\"2021-03-28\",\"110\":\"2021-03-28\",\"111\":\"2021-03-28\",\"112\":\"2021-03-28\",\"113\":\"2021-03-28\",\"114\":\"2021-03-28\",\"115\":\"2021-03-28\",\"116\":\"2021-03-28\",\"117\":\"2021-03-28\",\"118\":\"2021-03-28\",\"119\":\"2021-03-28\",\"120\":\"2021-03-28\",\"121\":\"2021-03-28\",\"122\":\"2021-03-28\",\"123\":\"2021-03-28\",\"124\":\"2021-03-28\",\"125\":\"2021-03-28\",\"126\":\"2021-03-28\",\"127\":\"2021-03-28\",\"128\":\"2021-03-28\",\"129\":\"2021-03-28\",\"130\":\"2021-03-28\",\"131\":\"2021-03-28\",\"132\":\"2021-03-28\",\"133\":\"2021-03-28\",\"134\":\"2021-03-28\",\"135\":\"2021-03-28\",\"136\":\"2021-03-28\",\"137\":\"2021-03-28\",\"138\":\"2021-03-28\",\"139\":\"2021-03-28\",\"140\":\"2021-03-28\",\"141\":\"2021-03-28\",\"142\":\"2021-03-28\",\"143\":\"2021-03-28\",\"144\":\"2021-03-28\",\"145\":\"2021-03-28\",\"146\":\"2021-03-28\",\"147\":\"2021-03-28\",\"148\":\"2021-03-28\",\"149\":\"2021-03-28\",\"150\":\"2021-03-28\",\"151\":\"2021-03-28\",\"152\":\"2021-03-28\",\"153\":\"2021-03-28\",\"154\":\"2021-03-28\",\"155\":\"2021-03-28\",\"156\":\"2021-03-28\",\"157\":\"2021-03-28\",\"158\":\"2021-03-28\",\"159\":\"2021-03-28\",\"160\":\"2021-03-28\",\"161\":\"2021-03-28\",\"162\":\"2021-03-28\",\"163\":\"2021-03-28\",\"164\":\"2021-03-28\",\"165\":\"2021-03-28\",\"166\":\"2021-03-28\",\"167\":\"2021-03-28\",\"168\":\"2021-03-28\",\"169\":\"2021-03-28\",\"170\":\"2021-03-28\",\"171\":\"2021-03-28\",\"172\":\"2021-03-28\",\"173\":\"2021-03-28\",\"174\":\"2021-03-28\",\"175\":\"2021-03-28\",\"176\":\"2021-03-28\",\"177\":\"2021-03-28\",\"178\":\"2021-03-28\",\"179\":\"2021-03-28\",\"180\":\"2021-03-28\",\"181\":\"2021-03-28\",\"182\":\"2021-03-28\",\"183\":\"2021-03-28\",\"184\":\"2021-03-28\",\"185\":\"2021-03-28\",\"186\":\"2021-03-28\",\"187\":\"2021-03-28\",\"188\":\"2021-03-28\",\"189\":\"2021-03-28\",\"190\":\"2021-03-28\",\"191\":\"2021-03-28\",\"192\":\"2021-03-28\",\"193\":\"2021-03-28\",\"194\":\"2021-03-28\",\"195\":\"2021-03-28\",\"196\":\"2021-03-28\",\"197\":\"2021-03-28\",\"198\":\"2021-03-28\",\"199\":\"2021-03-28\",\"200\":\"2021-03-28\",\"201\":\"2021-03-28\",\"202\":\"2021-03-28\",\"203\":\"2021-03-28\",\"204\":\"2021-03-28\",\"205\":\"2021-03-28\",\"206\":\"2021-03-28\",\"207\":\"2021-03-28\",\"208\":\"2021-03-28\",\"209\":\"2021-03-28\",\"210\":\"2021-03-28\",\"211\":\"2021-03-28\",\"212\":\"2021-03-28\",\"213\":\"2021-03-28\",\"214\":\"2021-03-28\",\"215\":\"2021-03-28\",\"216\":\"2021-03-28\",\"217\":\"2021-03-28\",\"218\":\"2021-03-28\",\"219\":\"2021-03-28\",\"220\":\"2021-03-28\",\"221\":\"2021-03-28\",\"222\":\"2021-03-28\",\"223\":\"2021-03-28\",\"224\":\"2021-03-28\",\"225\":\"2021-03-28\",\"226\":\"2021-03-28\"},
\"User Activity\":{\"0\":0,\"1\":0,\"2\":0,\"3\":0,\"4\":0,\"5\":0,\"6\":0,\"7\":0,\"8\":85110000,\"9\":0,\"10\":0,\"11\":0,\"12\":0,\"13\":0,\"14\":0,\"15\":0,\"16\":0,\"17\":0,\"18\":0,\"19\":0,\"20\":0,\"21\":0,\"22\":0,\"23\":27780000,\"24\":0,\"25\":0,\"26\":0,\"27\":0,\"28\":0,\"29\":0,\"30\":0,\"31\":0,\"32\":0,\"33\":0,\"34\":0,\"35\":0,\"36\":0,\"37\":0,\"38\":0,\"39\":0,\"40\":0,\"41\":0,\"42\":0,\"43\":0,\"44\":0,\"45\":0,\"46\":0,\"47\":0,\"48\":0,\"49\":0,\"50\":0,\"51\":0,\"52\":0,\"53\":0,\"54\":0,\"55\":0,\"56\":0,\"57\":0,\"58\":0,\"59\":0,\"60\":0,\"61\":0,\"62\":0,\"63\":0,\"64\":0,\"65\":0,\"66\":0,\"67\":0,\"68\":0,\"69\":0,\"70\":0,\"71\":0,\"72\":0,\"73\":0,\"74\":0,\"75\":0,\"76\":194350000,\"77\":0,\"78\":0,\"79\":0,\"80\":0,\"81\":0,\"82\":0,\"83\":0,\"84\":0,\"85\":0,\"86\":0,\"87\":0,\"88\":0,\"89\":0,\"90\":0,\"91\":0,\"92\":0,\"93\":0,\"94\":0,\"95\":0,\"96\":0,\"97\":0,\"98\":0,\"99\":0,\"100\":0,\"101\":0,\"102\":0,\"103\":0,\"104\":0,\"105\":0,\"106\":51370000,\"107\":0,\"108\":0,\"109\":0,\"110\":0,\"111\":0,\"112\":0,\"113\":0,\"114\":0,\"115\":0,\"116\":0,\"117\":0,\"118\":0,\"119\":0,\"120\":180797500,\"121\":0,\"122\":0,\"123\":0,\"124\":33331250,\"125\":0,\"126\":0,\"127\":0,\"128\":0,\"129\":0,\"130\":0,\"131\":0,\"132\":0,\"133\":0,\"134\":0,\"135\":0,\"136\":0,\"137\":0,\"138\":0,\"139\":0,\"140\":0,\"141\":0,\"142\":0,\"143\":0,\"144\":0,\"145\":0,\"146\":0,\"147\":0,\"148\":0,\"149\":0,\"150\":0,\"151\":0,\"152\":0,\"153\":23210000,\"154\":0,\"155\":0,\"156\":0,\"157\":0,\"158\":0,\"159\":0,\"160\":0,\"161\":0,\"162\":0,\"163\":0,\"164\":0,\"165\":0,\"166\":0,\"167\":0,\"168\":0,\"169\":0,\"170\":0,\"171\":32965000,\"172\":76040000,\"173\":3890000,\"174\":0,\"175\":0,\"176\":0,\"177\":0,\"178\":0,\"179\":0,\"180\":0,\"181\":0,\"182\":0,\"183\":65360000,\"184\":0,\"185\":0,\"186\":0,\"187\":0,\"188\":0,\"189\":0,\"190\":0,\"191\":0,\"192\":0,\"193\":0,\"194\":0,\"195\":0,\"196\":0,\"197\":0,\"198\":0,\"199\":0,\"200\":0,\"201\":0,\"202\":0,\"203\":0,\"204\":0,\"205\":0,\"206\":0,\"207\":0,\"208\":0,\"209\":0,\"210\":0,\"211\":0,\"212\":0,\"213\":0,\"214\":0,\"215\":365435000,\"216\":0,\"217\":0,\"218\":0,\"219\":0,\"220\":0,\"221\":0,\"222\":0,\"223\":0,\"224\":0,\"225\":0,\"226\":0}}') as json
,json:Day
,json:"User Activity"
;
```

So to unroll your column data, you need to loop across one column, lets use `Day`, and then access the `User Activity` via the `key` from the Flatten

```
WITH data AS (
    select 
    parse_json('{\"Day\":{\"0\":\"2021-03-28\",\"1\":\"2021-03-28\",\"2\":\"2021-03-28\",\"3\":\"2021-03-28\",\"4\":\"2021-03-28\",\"5\":\"2021-03-28\",\"6\":\"2021-03-28\",\"7\":\"2021-03-28\",\"8\":\"2021-03-28\",\"9\":\"2021-03-28\",\"10\":\"2021-03-28\",\"11\":\"2021-03-28\",\"12\":\"2021-03-28\",\"13\":\"2021-03-28\",\"14\":\"2021-03-28\",\"15\":\"2021-03-28\",\"16\":\"2021-03-28\",\"17\":\"2021-03-28\",\"18\":\"2021-03-28\",\"19\":\"2021-03-28\",\"20\":\"2021-03-28\",\"21\":\"2021-03-28\",\"22\":\"2021-03-28\",\"23\":\"2021-03-28\",\"24\":\"2021-03-28\",\"25\":\"2021-03-28\",\"26\":\"2021-03-28\",\"27\":\"2021-03-28\",\"28\":\"2021-03-28\",\"29\":\"2021-03-28\",\"30\":\"2021-03-28\",\"31\":\"2021-03-28\",\"32\":\"2021-03-28\",\"33\":\"2021-03-28\",\"34\":\"2021-03-28\",\"35\":\"2021-03-28\",\"36\":\"2021-03-28\",\"37\":\"2021-03-28\",\"38\":\"2021-03-28\",\"39\":\"2021-03-28\",\"40\":\"2021-03-28\",\"41\":\"2021-03-28\",\"42\":\"2021-03-28\",\"43\":\"2021-03-28\",\"44\":\"2021-03-28\",\"45\":\"2021-03-28\",\"46\":\"2021-03-28\",\"47\":\"2021-03-28\",\"48\":\"2021-03-28\",\"49\":\"2021-03-28\",\"50\":\"2021-03-28\",\"51\":\"2021-03-28\",\"52\":\"2021-03-28\",\"53\":\"2021-03-28\",\"54\":\"2021-03-28\",\"55\":\"2021-03-28\",\"56\":\"2021-03-28\",\"57\":\"2021-03-28\",\"58\":\"2021-03-28\",\"59\":\"2021-03-28\",\"60\":\"2021-03-28\",\"61\":\"2021-03-28\",\"62\":\"2021-03-28\",\"63\":\"2021-03-28\",\"64\":\"2021-03-28\",\"65\":\"2021-03-28\",\"66\":\"2021-03-28\",\"67\":\"2021-03-28\",\"68\":\"2021-03-28\",\"69\":\"2021-03-28\",\"70\":\"2021-03-28\",\"71\":\"2021-03-28\",\"72\":\"2021-03-28\",\"73\":\"2021-03-28\",\"74\":\"2021-03-28\",\"75\":\"2021-03-28\",\"76\":\"2021-03-28\",\"77\":\"2021-03-28\",\"78\":\"2021-03-28\",\"79\":\"2021-03-28\",\"80\":\"2021-03-28\",\"81\":\"2021-03-28\",\"82\":\"2021-03-28\",\"83\":\"2021-03-28\",\"84\":\"2021-03-28\",\"85\":\"2021-03-28\",\"86\":\"2021-03-28\",\"87\":\"2021-03-28\",\"88\":\"2021-03-28\",\"89\":\"2021-03-28\",\"90\":\"2021-03-28\",\"91\":\"2021-03-28\",\"92\":\"2021-03-28\",\"93\":\"2021-03-28\",\"94\":\"2021-03-28\",\"95\":\"2021-03-28\",\"96\":\"2021-03-28\",\"97\":\"2021-03-28\",\"98\":\"2021-03-28\",\"99\":\"2021-03-28\",\"100\":\"2021-03-28\",\"101\":\"2021-03-28\",\"102\":\"2021-03-28\",\"103\":\"2021-03-28\",\"104\":\"2021-03-28\",\"105\":\"2021-03-28\",\"106\":\"2021-03-28\",\"107\":\"2021-03-28\",\"108\":\"2021-03-28\",\"109\":\"2021-03-28\",\"110\":\"2021-03-28\",\"111\":\"2021-03-28\",\"112\":\"2021-03-28\",\"113\":\"2021-03-28\",\"114\":\"2021-03-28\",\"115\":\"2021-03-28\",\"116\":\"2021-03-28\",\"117\":\"2021-03-28\",\"118\":\"2021-03-28\",\"119\":\"2021-03-28\",\"120\":\"2021-03-28\",\"121\":\"2021-03-28\",\"122\":\"2021-03-28\",\"123\":\"2021-03-28\",\"124\":\"2021-03-28\",\"125\":\"2021-03-28\",\"126\":\"2021-03-28\",\"127\":\"2021-03-28\",\"128\":\"2021-03-28\",\"129\":\"2021-03-28\",\"130\":\"2021-03-28\",\"131\":\"2021-03-28\",\"132\":\"2021-03-28\",\"133\":\"2021-03-28\",\"134\":\"2021-03-28\",\"135\":\"2021-03-28\",\"136\":\"2021-03-28\",\"137\":\"2021-03-28\",\"138\":\"2021-03-28\",\"139\":\"2021-03-28\",\"140\":\"2021-03-28\",\"141\":\"2021-03-28\",\"142\":\"2021-03-28\",\"143\":\"2021-03-28\",\"144\":\"2021-03-28\",\"145\":\"2021-03-28\",\"146\":\"2021-03-28\",\"147\":\"2021-03-28\",\"148\":\"2021-03-28\",\"149\":\"2021-03-28\",\"150\":\"2021-03-28\",\"151\":\"2021-03-28\",\"152\":\"2021-03-28\",\"153\":\"2021-03-28\",\"154\":\"2021-03-28\",\"155\":\"2021-03-28\",\"156\":\"2021-03-28\",\"157\":\"2021-03-28\",\"158\":\"2021-03-28\",\"159\":\"2021-03-28\",\"160\":\"2021-03-28\",\"161\":\"2021-03-28\",\"162\":\"2021-03-28\",\"163\":\"2021-03-28\",\"164\":\"2021-03-28\",\"165\":\"2021-03-28\",\"166\":\"2021-03-28\",\"167\":\"2021-03-28\",\"168\":\"2021-03-28\",\"169\":\"2021-03-28\",\"170\":\"2021-03-28\",\"171\":\"2021-03-28\",\"172\":\"2021-03-28\",\"173\":\"2021-03-28\",\"174\":\"2021-03-28\",\"175\":\"2021-03-28\",\"176\":\"2021-03-28\",\"177\":\"2021-03-28\",\"178\":\"2021-03-28\",\"179\":\"2021-03-28\",\"180\":\"2021-03-28\",\"181\":\"2021-03-28\",\"182\":\"2021-03-28\",\"183\":\"2021-03-28\",\"184\":\"2021-03-28\",\"185\":\"2021-03-28\",\"186\":\"2021-03-28\",\"187\":\"2021-03-28\",\"188\":\"2021-03-28\",\"189\":\"2021-03-28\",\"190\":\"2021-03-28\",\"191\":\"2021-03-28\",\"192\":\"2021-03-28\",\"193\":\"2021-03-28\",\"194\":\"2021-03-28\",\"195\":\"2021-03-28\",\"196\":\"2021-03-28\",\"197\":\"2021-03-28\",\"198\":\"2021-03-28\",\"199\":\"2021-03-28\",\"200\":\"2021-03-28\",\"201\":\"2021-03-28\",\"202\":\"2021-03-28\",\"203\":\"2021-03-28\",\"204\":\"2021-03-28\",\"205\":\"2021-03-28\",\"206\":\"2021-03-28\",\"207\":\"2021-03-28\",\"208\":\"2021-03-28\",\"209\":\"2021-03-28\",\"210\":\"2021-03-28\",\"211\":\"2021-03-28\",\"212\":\"2021-03-28\",\"213\":\"2021-03-28\",\"214\":\"2021-03-28\",\"215\":\"2021-03-28\",\"216\":\"2021-03-28\",\"217\":\"2021-03-28\",\"218\":\"2021-03-28\",\"219\":\"2021-03-28\",\"220\":\"2021-03-28\",\"221\":\"2021-03-28\",\"222\":\"2021-03-28\",\"223\":\"2021-03-28\",\"224\":\"2021-03-28\",\"225\":\"2021-03-28\",\"226\":\"2021-03-28\"},
    \"User Activity\":{\"0\":0,\"1\":0,\"2\":0,\"3\":0,\"4\":0,\"5\":0,\"6\":0,\"7\":0,\"8\":85110000,\"9\":0,\"10\":0,\"11\":0,\"12\":0,\"13\":0,\"14\":0,\"15\":0,\"16\":0,\"17\":0,\"18\":0,\"19\":0,\"20\":0,\"21\":0,\"22\":0,\"23\":27780000,\"24\":0,\"25\":0,\"26\":0,\"27\":0,\"28\":0,\"29\":0,\"30\":0,\"31\":0,\"32\":0,\"33\":0,\"34\":0,\"35\":0,\"36\":0,\"37\":0,\"38\":0,\"39\":0,\"40\":0,\"41\":0,\"42\":0,\"43\":0,\"44\":0,\"45\":0,\"46\":0,\"47\":0,\"48\":0,\"49\":0,\"50\":0,\"51\":0,\"52\":0,\"53\":0,\"54\":0,\"55\":0,\"56\":0,\"57\":0,\"58\":0,\"59\":0,\"60\":0,\"61\":0,\"62\":0,\"63\":0,\"64\":0,\"65\":0,\"66\":0,\"67\":0,\"68\":0,\"69\":0,\"70\":0,\"71\":0,\"72\":0,\"73\":0,\"74\":0,\"75\":0,\"76\":194350000,\"77\":0,\"78\":0,\"79\":0,\"80\":0,\"81\":0,\"82\":0,\"83\":0,\"84\":0,\"85\":0,\"86\":0,\"87\":0,\"88\":0,\"89\":0,\"90\":0,\"91\":0,\"92\":0,\"93\":0,\"94\":0,\"95\":0,\"96\":0,\"97\":0,\"98\":0,\"99\":0,\"100\":0,\"101\":0,\"102\":0,\"103\":0,\"104\":0,\"105\":0,\"106\":51370000,\"107\":0,\"108\":0,\"109\":0,\"110\":0,\"111\":0,\"112\":0,\"113\":0,\"114\":0,\"115\":0,\"116\":0,\"117\":0,\"118\":0,\"119\":0,\"120\":180797500,\"121\":0,\"122\":0,\"123\":0,\"124\":33331250,\"125\":0,\"126\":0,\"127\":0,\"128\":0,\"129\":0,\"130\":0,\"131\":0,\"132\":0,\"133\":0,\"134\":0,\"135\":0,\"136\":0,\"137\":0,\"138\":0,\"139\":0,\"140\":0,\"141\":0,\"142\":0,\"143\":0,\"144\":0,\"145\":0,\"146\":0,\"147\":0,\"148\":0,\"149\":0,\"150\":0,\"151\":0,\"152\":0,\"153\":23210000,\"154\":0,\"155\":0,\"156\":0,\"157\":0,\"158\":0,\"159\":0,\"160\":0,\"161\":0,\"162\":0,\"163\":0,\"164\":0,\"165\":0,\"166\":0,\"167\":0,\"168\":0,\"169\":0,\"170\":0,\"171\":32965000,\"172\":76040000,\"173\":3890000,\"174\":0,\"175\":0,\"176\":0,\"177\":0,\"178\":0,\"179\":0,\"180\":0,\"181\":0,\"182\":0,\"183\":65360000,\"184\":0,\"185\":0,\"186\":0,\"187\":0,\"188\":0,\"189\":0,\"190\":0,\"191\":0,\"192\":0,\"193\":0,\"194\":0,\"195\":0,\"196\":0,\"197\":0,\"198\":0,\"199\":0,\"200\":0,\"201\":0,\"202\":0,\"203\":0,\"204\":0,\"205\":0,\"206\":0,\"207\":0,\"208\":0,\"209\":0,\"210\":0,\"211\":0,\"212\":0,\"213\":0,\"214\":0,\"215\":365435000,\"216\":0,\"217\":0,\"218\":0,\"219\":0,\"220\":0,\"221\":0,\"222\":0,\"223\":0,\"224\":0,\"225\":0,\"226\":0}}') as json
)
select d.value as day
    ,json:"User Activity"[d.key] as "User Activity"
from data, table (flatten(input=>json:Day)) d;
```

gives first ~30 rows:

```
DAY User Activity
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    51370000
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    180797500
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    0
"2021-03-28"    33331250
"2021-03-28"    0
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do it you think? That feels like a lot for sql, do you know if should be done in pandas instead? As well why do you say fundamentally this is a rather gross way to process data, . If I have a dataframe of data, and want to store it in a datalake as json, what is a non gross way of doing so? @Simeon Pilgrim

Comment: @0004 sending nested object oh which you extract rows in snowflake feels rather wrong to me. Two reasons if you can send many objects, that can scale beyond the limit of a json object being 16mb, and why turn it from a list into arrays of values. Also if you have to send it as one json object it seems just the same to have an array of objects, verse and object of arrays.

Comment: appreciate you sharing your perspective. But given my use case - if I have a dataframe of data and want to store it in a data lake and then use snowflake to transform/load my datawarehouse - how would you go about it? The reason I am not storing it as a csv in the datalake as it is easier to add new fields . @Simeon Pilgrim

Comment: If your data lake is your primary concern then sure, do what's best for that. I was just suggesting if you have the data in panda's and you are sending it to snowflake turning it into column form buys you nothing, and limits you.

Comment: @0004 ignoring my opinion that it seems like this is not "how you should structure your data", given you are injecting the data you mention the above SQL is how to transform it into rows in snowflake, which I believe was your question.

Comment: Still not clear as to what you advise to do , if you were in this situation. Taking data that is in a dataframe and pushing it first into a lake and then into a datawarehouse