# Best data format to load into snowflake table from MySQL (JSON or XML for a column)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to migrate Aurora MySQL table is has 3 billions rows and 7TB storage .
I am new to Snowflake so need some suggestions about the file format .

The data type is simple except two columns which is `longtext` and stores `xml` data in MySQL table .
This is my MySQL table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `app_event` (
`ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DETAILS` longtext,
`OBJECT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DATE_TIME` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`SUMMARY` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

DETAILS column and SUMMARY column stores xml file of now .
A sample row is

```
6tgbcr45345o82mcrzz,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><CasePayload><caseId>5f5475-21cf-4c7e-8071-574a1ef78981</caseId><providerTypes>WATCHLIST</providerTypes> ,9/16/2020 9:45,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><CaseEventSummary><providerTypes>WATCHLIST</providerTypes>
```

This is just a sample data and while moving we need to convert xml to json and store into Snowflake table .

We are thinking to use Kinesis for this but when Kinesis delivers data into s3 it converts to json .

So question is what is best data format to load into Snowflake ?
Shall we convert to CSV and make xml to json on the fly and store into CSV or json is good ?
Like this

```
{
      "ID":"6tgbcr45345o82mcrzz",
      "DETAILS":{
         "CasePayload":{
            "caseId":"5f5475-21cf-4c7e-8071-574a1ef78981",
            "providerTypes":"WATCHLIST"
         }
      },
      "OBJECT":"TEST",
      "DATE_TIME":"9/16/2020 9:45",
      "SUMMARY":{
         "screenCaseEventSummary":{
            "providerTypes":"WATCHLIST"
         }
      }
   }
```

Which is good in terms of Select ?
I need to query on element of json and that one of the main reason to convert xml to json but rest all column we want to store a column .

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake understands JSON and XML, you can work with both.

If I had to choose, I would choose JSON - as XML support is still in preview (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html).

I'd also consider how you are currently querying the XML strings, in case you want to minimize the effort to translate queries (in that case, I would keep working with the XML objects).

Comment: Is JSON is better in select perspective or column structure is better.I need to have fast select so which one is better to store

Comment: JSON is nice for evolving schemas - column structure is better when you have a well defined schema, and makes writing queries easier

Answer (score 0):

More to Felipe's point. If you can use JSON, and make sure you compress you files.

For both FLATTEN will be your best friend for unlooping array's. But the syntax for JSON is like

```
json_column:Object_Name:Sub_Obj_Name::int
```

which can also be done via

```
json_get(json_column, 'Object_Name.Sub_Obj_Name')
```

but the former looks so much nicer, while XML is a dog breakfast (IMHO)

```
get(xmlget(xmlget(xmlget(xml,'header',0), 'companyinfo', 0), 'companyid'),'$') as companyid
```

see this [XML answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934873/combining-multiple-txmlmap-output-values-to-a-single-snowflake-table/66937004#66937004) verse this [JSON answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859846/dataframe-to-json-then-flatten-in-snowflake/66862443#66862443)

Comment: But if we use JSON will select in large table we slow compare to normal column structure ? Also does JSON support search optimization .Insert is fine but in select view which is better to use ?

Comment: @SUDARSHAN I assume you were asking how best to move the semi-structured data from external source to Snowflake, in which case my suggestion that JSON is easier still holds. We have TB of "raw" JSON which is how we ingest our data, but there we transform/extra the data we use on a daily basis into structured tables that are structed to perform for the work we do. The JSON is looked at for those adhoc question, and something we change how we extra the data, as we find this we want in the primary tables. But again JSON vs XML the XML is horrible to work with in comparison.